# ILoggerFactory/ILoggerProvider disposal not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have implemented a custom ILogger in a ASP.NET Core API. Here is the LoggerProvider code:

```
 public class LoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        public IConfiguration Config { get; }
        private MyLog logger;
        public LoggerProvider(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Config = config;
        }
        
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
           var logger = new MyLog(Config);
           loggers.Add(logger);
        }
      
        public void Dispose()
        {
           foreach (var logger in loggers)
           {
             logger.Dispose();
           }
        }
    }
```

here is MyLog impl:

```
public class MyLog : ILogger, IDisposable
    {        
        public MyLog(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Config = config;
            LogMessages = new List<LogMessage>();
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {         
            return new Disposable();
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var message = formatter(state, exception);
            CacheLogMessage(message, logLevel);
        }
    
        private class Disposable : IDisposable
        {
            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {            
            SubmitLogs();
        }

        private void CacheLogMessage(string message, LogLevel logLevel)
        {            
             // create log message
            LogMessages.Add(lm);
        }
        

        private void SubmitLogs()
        {
            // submit logs
        }
```

and here is how I am getting an instance of ILogger for integration testing:

```
servicesProvider = ServiceProvider.BuildDi(config);

loggerFactory = servicesProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider(config));
logger = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyLog>>();
```

In MyLog I have implemented a caching logic that collects the log messages and sends them when MyLog is disposed. Preferably after the http request has finished.

The problem seems to be that the LoggerFactory is not being disposed after a httprequest. I manually trigger the displosal during the integration test but it doesn´t seem to trigger when running the api on iis.

Is there a way to configure the lifetime of the LoggerFactory e.g. to scoped to trigger the disposal? If not is there an alternative solution to trigger the dispose function of MyLog or a way to detect when a http request has finished?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: It would have been strange if logger factory or provider were per scope, doesn't make much sense for their use case. Logger itself however should be disposed if implements disposable and is scoped, but hard to tell since you didn't provide logger code, and your provider code won't compile.

Comment: Thanks @Evk for your reply. Please see the updated quesiton with the logger code. Since MyLog is instantiated within LoggerProvider how can I make it scoped?